# Is there anyway to get a consistent border around images in IE and Microsoft Edge without random parts disappearing?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Is there anyway to get a consistent border around images for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge browsers? At different breakpoints (if you zoom in and out), the specific sides the border shows up on varies. Sometimes it shows the border on the top and left sides, sometimes the top and right sides, etc. I would like it to show up on all sides for all breakpoints.

I've tried:

- Putting a border around the `img` tag itself using the CSS border property
- Wrapping the image in a `div` tag with the CSS border property

EDIT: I've tried to update the border to 2px, and the border shows, but at certain breakpoints it grows larger/smaller, in an inconsistent manner + there is a slight padding in the image at certain breakpoints, . I believe something in IE/Edge causes the image borders to vary the border thickness in an inconsistent manner.

The code:

http://jsbin.com/befuqekofa/1/edit?html,output

```css
#image{
  border: solid 1px black;
}
#border {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

 </head>
<body>
  
  <img id = "image" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  <div id="border">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "half a pixel" doesn't make much sense. a pixel is either whole, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: "Half a pixel" is indeed a real measurement, though that might have been what was causing the problem, since browsers will round, usually alternating up and down, in order to prevent unsightly wrapping. On a hi-DPI screen (i.e. Retina), 0.5px should appear consistent at any screen size.

Comment: Have updated the code to 1px, and it is still a problem.

Comment: Fwiw, the second image in your example does not fit in its parent `DIV` that should be 502×502 (to account for borders of the image itself) instead of 500×500 (equal to width of the image without accounting for its borders).

Comment: That is true.. have edited the example to fit the original intention of the example (1px around image).  I have decided to opt with a Photoshop based solution by putting the border directly on the image, although it would be nice to see a CSS solution, as this should be somewhat of a common task, and I'm sure this problem has come up before for someone somewhere. If someone comes up with the answer, I will still check it the answer, and list it as the correct solution, if it is. I am still curious.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with zooming in and zooming out a web page is that it will always have some weird artifacts, and I'm not sure about your question.

If you're trying to do breakpoints (`@media`), why would you zoom in and out the page? The scaling that devices might apply ( with higher pixel dpi screens ), they have a better way for drawing/rendering does kind of stuff. So maybe, no, for zooming in and out on IE and Edge. I think that's how it's just rendered. But you'll have that issue even with background-positioning, floats etc... and maybe other browsers.

If you want to have like a better scaling border, so it will change dynamically for zooming and breakpoints, you could use `em` or `rem` depending on your structure.

Hope that makes sense,
Cheers!

Comment: I'm using this example as an approximation for a problem I'm having on another site. At all breakpoints on that site, it does not show up on all sides. And as a web developer, you need to factor various zoom levels. Some people will have their browser shown up on different zoom levels (90%,100%,110% probably the most common). EM/REM solution does not work.